How to open block device files?
I've just installed ubuntu. I have an SSD and an HDD. I installed ubuntu on the SSD, and didn't format the HDD, now my HDD data lies in my files, but when I'm trying to open it it says "There is no app installed for "Block Device" files". My question might sound really silly, but I have no idea how to solve this problem and I couldn't find any explanation on the internet either. Thanks in advice

Do you want to open the block device or look at the filesystem on the device?
If you want to actually read the block device, the normal open() and read() system calls will work, but you may have to read data in multiples of the size of a block.  But I bet this isn't what you want.
More likely you want to mount the block device so you can access the filesystem rather than the raw data on the device.  When you mount the device, it attaches the filesystem on the device at the specified directory.  Note that block devices can be partitioned, so it may show up as (for instance) /dev/sdb for the whole device and /dev/sdb1 for the first partition.  If there are partitions, you probably want to mount those and not the device itself.
There are (at least) three ways to mount a block device:

mount it manually on an empty directory:  sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount it with the the graphical file manager tool (by clicking on the disk on the left pane)
mount it the same way the file manager would, but by command line: udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1 which will put it somewhere in /media/
If it is a removable device and you have automatic mounting of removable devices enabled, the above command should be run automatically for you on device insertion

Note only the first of these commands needs sudo.
